# Python module needs to write files to a directory but permission is blocked

Tags: python, packaging, ioerror

This is my first time writing a python module so I don't know some customs. My module needs to write data and store it somewhere. I decided to do so in some nested folder underneath the location of my modules egg within site-packages.

However, when running the script on a computer after installing it via setup.py,

I'm getting errors when trying to create a directory. I managed to get around creating/reading from files by making all my

```
open('file.txt', 'r+') # into
open('file.txt', 'r') 
# and same respectively for writes.


# os.mkdir() is causing an IOError permissions denied.
```

But it still won't let me create directories! Via an `IOError` permissions denied.

NOTE: I'm aware that you can write/read anything from some special dirs, like `/tmp`, but I'd prefer to do it in the egg.

I feel that this task is a must do also, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This seems like an issue related to your file system (which you haven't mentioned by the way), rather than anything related to the programming language.

Comment: Try running the script as administrator.

Comment: I ran as sudo and it worked, thanks. Asad what do you mean by filesystem? Like do you mean i'm on unix or windows or..

Comment: Yeh, but on linux you need to be more specific.For example, Ubuntu uses ext3 (I'm pretty sure)

Comment: "I decided to do so in some nested folder underneath the location of my modules egg within site-packages." Uh... NO.

Comment: Ignacio is that considered bad practice? Sorry lol

Comment: Where would you suggest writing/reading/putting files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application data should be stored under either `%APPDATA%`, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, or `~/.config`, depending on the platform. Create a directory for the module within one of those locations. Or better yet, have the application tell you where your data should be located.

Comment: Ah, this is cool, never knew about this protocol. Is there some website where I can see more about various folders and their purposes?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html